# I've upgraded my php but <? ?> codes started to not work?

Tags: web

I've upgraded my php. But all of sudden none of my code is working now. It shows me `<? ?>`. PHP tags suddenly started to not work. Why, and how can I fix it?

Comment: What version did you upgrade from and which version did you upgrade to?

Comment: Which webserver and PHP module are you using?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to clarify so that this can be answered.  Right now, there is little information to work with.

Comment: short_open_tag = On solved my problem. Thank you

Comment: @StephenOstermiller Sorry I didn't see messages under my question. I'm new here. Thank you very much to you also for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is easy. I'll share it but let me first tell you that using `<? ?>` short tags are not suggested.

Please from now on try to use full `<?php ?>` tags.

And solution is `short_open_tag = On` in your php.ini